# Can't add Android platform and build ionic project anymore?

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

So I wanted to start a new ionic project by writing:
`ionic start Ionic1 blank`

After that I moved to that new directory and wanted to add android platform:
`ionic platform add android`

I then got this error:

> Error: Failed to fetch platform android
>   Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
>   Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
>   Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/think/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/4.1.1/package/.npmignore'

I don't know why this happens. I tried these:

1) change the permision with

```
chmod 744 /home/think/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/4.1.1/package/.npmignore
```

2) uninstalled and installed nodejs, cordova, ionic, etc.

3) Executed with `sudo ionic platform add android` (but "`sudo`" is not necessary i think since I added android platform before in other projects without having to write "`sudo`" )

Still it's somehow not possible to add a platform.

I'm on ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have android SDK manager installed.

I can build and run my other ionic projects that I created earlier. But since yesterday I can't build new projects anymore. It happened when I iupdated to ionic 1.7.13. I tried to downgrade ionic to an earlier version but that wouldn't solve the issue either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what went wrong. i just installed cordova and ionic again and now it's working. For those who encountered the same problem: The commands I executed:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
sudo npm install -g ionic
```

After that add, build, and run the project just as usual.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is a cache problem of cordova. Delete the cache and try to add the platform again:

```
rm -rf ~/.cordova
```

Comment: I did. Then I typed in "ionic platform add android" and it said: "Platform android already added". I then tried to build it with "ionic build android" and it would say: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/think/dev/Ionic1/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml'". Tried to change permission and build again but got the same error message again.

Answer (score -4):

Try adding it with cordova instead of ionic.

```
cordova platform add android
```